# Best way to set the permissions for a specific user on a specific folder on a remote machine?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

We have a deployment system at my office where we can automatically deploy a given build of our code to a specified dev environment (dev01, dev02, etc.).

These dev environments are generalized virtual machines, so our system has to configure them automatically. We have a new system requirement with our next version; we need to give certain user accounts read/write access to certain folders (specifically, giving the ASPNET user read/write to a logging folder).

I'm pretty sure we could do this with WMI or scripts (we use Sysinternals PSTools in a few places for deployment), but I'm not sure what is the best way to do it. The deployment system is written in C# 2.0, the dev environment is a VM with Windows XP. The VM is on the same domain as the deployment system and I have administrator access.

Edit: There's not really a right answer for this, so I'm hesitant to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to investigate using a Powershell script There are a lot powershell community snap ins to support VMs and active directory.

[Active Directory Script Rescources](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_active_directory.htm#ADUC_(Active_Directory_Users_and_Computers)_)

[Powershell Script Library](http://www.myitforum.com/myITWiki/Default.aspx?Page=WPScripts&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

[Microsoft Script Resources](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/msh/ad/default.mspx?mfr=true)

[VMWARE VI Toolkit (for Windows)](http://blogs.vmware.com/vipowershell/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can run scripts, it might be as simple as runing the CACLS command on the VM. Perhaps just have your deployment script read in a config and run the appropriate CACLs commands.